# P-table dontWhen I cloned the project again on my machine and npm install

Tags: angular, package.json

This is my package.json
{
"name": "mom-shop-fe",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
"test": "ng test"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
"abp-ng2-module": "^8.0.0",
"boostrap": "^2.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
"chart.js": "^4.3.0",
"date-fns": "^2.30.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.4",
"mdb-ui-kit": "^6.2.0",
"modal-module": "^1.3.1",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"ng-image-slider": "^7.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
"ngx-bootstrap-modal": "^2.0.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^16.1.0",
"perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.5",
"primeicons": "^6.0.1",
"primeng": "^15.4.1",
"rxjs": "~7.8.0",
"tslib": "^2.3.0",
"zone.js": "~0.12.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.2",
"@angular/cli": "~15.2.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
"@schematics/angular": "^15.2.5",
"@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
"jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
"karma": "~6.4.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
"typescript": "~4.9.4"
}
}

I tried deleting node_modules and npm i again but still no data

Comment: i think the reason is due to conflict between package. But I still don't have a solution